# Map url not displaying on the browserfield for 5.0 OS blackberry

Tags: blackberry, dictionary

When I am trying to display a map url on the browserfield, I was able to display it on the os 6.0 and above when it comes to OS 5.0 it is been displaying the plain white screen with sign in option, when i click on the sign in option and try to login my google credentials i have getting the error like

https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth

The Specified HTTP method is not supported

By doing so also my issue is like i am not able to display the map on the browser my url will be like this

http://www.advainc.com/mobileadvantage/Map/default.aspx?saddr=46.822609,-114.079847+to:46.825311,-114.078487+to:46.82565,-114.080534+to:46.827338,-114.085307+to:46.843613,-114.11006+to:46.843613,-114.11006

Thanks in advance

Comment: any luck solving the issue? I am having a similar problem - unable to open google maps on the browser..